# What plots and summary statistics are usually used for exploratory data analysis of multivariate time series?

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, multivariate-regression, time-varying-covariate, exploratory-data-analysis

For multivariate cross-sectional data, tools such as scatterplot matrices, the five numbers summary, faceted boxplots and so on, allow an efficient exploration of a new data set, and can suggest how the conditional mean of the response $Y$ depends on the predictors. For example, I could see that the dependence of $E[Y|X_1,X_2]$ on $X_1$ is fairly linear, while the dependence on $X_2$ is more complicated, which may suggest to fit the two models

$$ \begin{align} 
Y &= \alpha_1X_1+s(X_2)+\epsilon  \\ 
Y &= \alpha_1X_1+s(X_2)+t(X_1,X2)+\epsilon \end{align}$$

and compare the cross-validation errors.

In the case of multivariate time series, things seem more complicated. Assume I have a discrete-time random process $Y(t_i)$, which I want to model as a function of some of its lags, other discrete-time random processes $X_1(t_i),\dots,X_p(t_i)$ and possibly some random variables $Z_1,\dots,Z_d$ (I think this is a convenient model for a multivariate time series, but feel free to correct me if you disagree). Suppose also that I have a sample of $N$ such multivariate time series, possibly of different lengths.

Which (graphical and/or numerical) tools can I use to explore this dataset and get an idea of which model I could fit? If it helps, the goal is mostly prediction - I'm not overly interested in inference.